# Magento 2: Need to add custom module grid link in system config tab

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

I have created a custom module grid in admin and need to add grid link to system config custom tab. I am struggling with this.

Custom module

[image]

System config field

[image]

How I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question with screenshots ?

Comment: @kishan Updated my comment withs screenshots

Comment: @kishan Did you check this?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please review.

Comment: It seems like your screenshot explain that you want to set link in label and answer related to display in link field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show link in your system configuration, then please follow below steps :

You need to add field in your `system.xml` file like this

```
<field id="link" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Click here to see the logs</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Link</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Here we used `frontend_model` and we will create Block for it here in custom module..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Link.php

Content for this file..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Link extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<a href ="%s">%s</a>',
            rtrim($this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('custom/module/link'), '/'), //You need to change this link (Use your grid link like 'sales/order/index' will redirect you on order grid page.)
            __('Marketo Logs')
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it will works for you.

Comment: Yes, This works for me. You save my day. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: You're most welcome Buddy :)