# Hyperlink or Div is displaying on menu link in admin

Tags: magento2.4.2

In admin Stores->Configuration
div tag is displaying

[image]

My code is
`vendor/plumrocket/module-plumbase/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
      <tab id="plumrocket" translate="label" sortOrder="400">
        <label><![CDATA[
            <div style="padding-left:22px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh) left 50% no-repeat;">Plumrocket</div> ]]></label>
       </tab>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use single qoute instead of double qoute.

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
      <tab id="plumrocket" translate="label" sortOrder="400">
        <label><![CDATA[
            <div style='padding-left:22px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh) left 50% no-repeat;'>Plumrocket</div> ]]></label>
       </tab>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: i used single quote but still not working

Comment: @Vibhore, did you checked answer is working before posting ?

Comment: @Pawan  - No i did not checked it, that is why I used the word "Please try"

Answer (score 0):

Please try Blow Code.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
      <tab id="plumrocket" translate="label" sortOrder="400">
        <label>Plumrocket</label>
       </tab>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: if i want to put hyperlink in label Plumrocket then?

Comment: Please check the below URL https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294559/magento-2-need-to-add-custom-module-grid-link-in-system-config-tab