# How can I reach the location in the file where I can find the code of store->configuration of the admin panel?

Tags: admin, configuration, stores

[image]Need to access the location of this in the code. I need to change the code of options and need to clear the quotation mark which is rendering in html format.

Comment: Text you want to edit is `<label>` for `<tab>`.

Comment: in this pic it is rendering html and I need to fix it

Comment: <tab id="magecomp" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
         <label><![CDATA[<img src="https://www.magecomp.com/media/images/magecomp--extension.png" alt="MAGECOMP" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>]]></label>
  </tab> this I need to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system.xml` file which is used for system configuration:

file is located at :

> app/code/MageComp/{Modulename}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

**OR**

If it was insatll using composer:

> vendor/MageComp/{Modulename}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

**Note:** Just check what is your module name

Comment: https://5d5272cf0e.nxcli.net/iotivedo_admin/admin/system_config/index/key/ca328046855b21de3411939b9941ddb9ce9be5437b1287745a045e8559481c6c/ this is the url  so I guess module name is admin

Comment: Just remove `html` and use `<tab id="magecomp" translate="label" sortOrder="100"> <label>MAGECOMP</label></tab>`

Comment: but I need the image to be rendered not the html thats what I need to fix.

Comment: I think in recent version of magento they are not allowing "html". More importantly it is just an image of vendor. refer same issue at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339461/hyperlink-or-div-is-displaying-on-menu-link-in-admin

Comment: do you have any idea about this pawan https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339587/save-custom-fields-on-add-to-cart-button-click